# Derived from AuthorizeAttribute but User.Identity.Name is null unless using AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization, windows-authentication

So I've created a custom authorize attribute I use in a few places that is derived from an abstract base class which is derived from `AuthorizeAttribute`:

CustomAuthorizeAttributeBase.cs

```
public abstract class CustomAuthorizeAttributeBase : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public abstract string GetUsers();
    public abstract string GetRoles();
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.IsChildAction)
        {
            return;
        }
        filterContext.Result =
            new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary
            {
                {"controller", "NotAuthorized"},
                {"action", "Index"},
            });
    }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (GetUsers().IndexOf(httpContext.User.Identity.Name, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0 ||
            GetRoles().Split(',').Any(s => httpContext.User.IsInRole(s)))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

AreaLevelReadonly.cs

```
public class AreaLevelReadOnly : CustomAuthorizeAttributeBase
{
    public override string GetUsers()
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AreaReadonlyUsers"];
    }

    public override string GetRoles()
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AreaReadonlyRoles"];
    }
}
```

I also have some fairly simple code that gets me the currently logged in user:

UserIdentity.cs

```
public class UserIdentity : IUserIdentity
{

    public string GetUserName()
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1];
    }
}
```

However, when I add my AreaLevelReadonly attribute to my controllers, getUserName fails and returns an exception that `Name` is null. I agonized over it for about an hour before putting authorize attribute on there as well, at which point it magically started working again. So, what is so different on the implementation level that my attribute deriving from authorizeattribute doesn't cause the `Name` to be populated.

Note: Windows authentication is on for the area, and the code works, but I don't understand why the Readonly attribute isn't enough to trigger authorization and population of the `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`.

Edit: Working:

```
[AreaLevelReadonly]
[Authorize]
public class DeleteAreaDataController : Controller { 
    //etc 
    var username = _userIdentity.GetUserName(HttpContext);
    //etc
}
```

Exception on name:

```
[AreaLevelReadonly]
public class DeleteAreaDataController : Controller { 
    //etc
    var username = _userIdentity.GetUserName(HttpContext);
    //etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

More likely than not, you're accessing `User.Identity.Name` before it's populated. By including the standard `Authorize` attribute, as well, your code is then only running after the user has been authorized already and `User.Identity.Name` has been populated.

**EDIT**

Sorry, I misunderstood where the code attempting to call `User.Identity.Name` was running. Based on the belief that it was happening in your custom attribute, I was suggesting that you're trying to access it too early. However, I now see that you're calling it in your controller (although an explanation of what happens in `GetUserAccount(HttpContext)` would have helped.)

Anyways, your custom attribute obviously adds extra conditions on whether a user is authorized or not. When you return false, *there is no user*. It's not a situation where the user is "logged in" but not allowed to see the page. It's either there or it isn't. So the user is failing authorization based on your custom attribute (`User.Identity.Name` is null) but *is* authorized when you include `Authorize` (`User.Identity.Name` has a value).

Long and short, your `GetUserName` or `GetUserAccount` or whatever code needs to account for when the user has failed authorization. Or, if the user shouldn't be failing authorization, you'll need to look into why your custom attribute isn't working. Though, either way, you should still account for `User.Identity.Name` being null.

Comment: I feel that I made it fairly clear that I already know the the name isn't being populated. I'm trying to figure out what I need to do to make my authorize attribute custom implementation work without having to stack it with authorize attribute as well.

Comment: Oops, you caught me copying and pasting from two different projects. The name changed between them but the implementation was the same. Where _userAccountService.GetUserAccount() was actually _userIdentity.GetUserName() all along, my mistake.

Comment: If the user fails custom authorization then they will get sent to the NotAuthorized controller per the `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` override in `CustomAuthorizeAttributeBase` so they won't ever hit the `GetUserAccount` call...

Answer (score 0):

Your custom attribute is probably reading `User.Identity.Name` before you check that the user is authenticated.

In other words, in `IsAuthorized()`, before you read `User.Identity.Name`, you should be doing something like this:

```
if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    // Your custom code...
    return false;
}
```

The reason you need this is because Windows Authentication (at least for NTLM) is a 2-step negotiation process between the client and server (see https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX221693). There will be 2 requests - the first with no name, and the second with a name. You can test this yourself - the source code for `AuthorizeAttribute` is provided [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/AuthorizeAttribute.cs). Copy/paste that into your code and put a breakpoint in `IsAuthorized` - you will see that the breakpoint is hit twice. First time, the name is null, second time, it's set to your username.

So I think the solution is to either check `user.Identity.IsAuthenticated` at the start of your method, if you need to run custom code (as shown above), or alternatively if you only need to `return false`, simply replace the above code with `base.IsAuthorized()` which should do it for you.